# use the present tense in the sentence

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense

I have to do an exercise where I must use the present tense to fill the gap in this sentence :

> Kim ----------- (never /be) abroad. She'd love to visit other countries.

Is my answer correct if I say "Kim **has never been** abroad"? I used the present perfect to answer?

Comment: I can't think of any other answer which would make sense, although it is not the present tense.

Comment: Present tense would be "Kim is not abroad.", but it doesn't connect with the next sentence very well.

Comment: Technically, the present perfect is present tense - although it isn't normally what is meant by it.  For example, Quirk et al. see the present perfect as a combination of present tense and perfect aspect, while Huddleston & Pullum see it as a combination of the present tense (in the primary tense system) and the perfect tense (in the secondary tense system).

Comment: "She's always at home when I call her. Kim is never abroad." ??